# Switch to user link shortcode

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, users, user-roles

I am using the [User Switching](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/) plugin in order to allow sales agents to place an order on behalf of a customer.

I have a page called My Customers which uses toolset to return a list of their customers. I'd like to add a link that allows them to switch to each user on this page.

I have tried adding the following code to functions.php and receive a critical error on the page, code is [directly from the developer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/#can%20i%20add%20a%20custom%20%22switch%20to%22%20link%20to%20my%20own%20plugin%20or%20theme%3F).

```
// Add Shortcode
function userswitch_shortcode() {

    if ( method_exists( 'user_switching', 'maybe_switch_url' ) ) {
        $url = user_switching::maybe_switch_url( $target_user );
        if ( $url ) {
            printf(
                '<a href="%1$s">Switch to %2$s</a>',
                esc_url( $url ),
                esc_html( $target_user->display_name )
            );
        }
    }

}
add_shortcode( 'userswitch', 'userswitch_shortcode' );
```

```
2021/06/11 05:16:14 [error] 46260#46260: *335027 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to user_switching::maybe_switch_url() must be an instance of WP_User, null given, called in /www/healthlightshop_532/public/wp-content/themes/wai-child/functions.php on line 35 and defined in /www/healthlightshop_532/public/wp-content/plugins/user-switching/user-switching.php:757
Stack trace:
#0 /www/healthlightshop_532/public/wp-content/themes/wai-child/functions.php(35): user_switching::maybe_switch_url(NULL)
#1 /www/healthlightshop_532/public/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(343): userswitch_shortcode('', '', 'userswitch')
#2 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array)
#3 /www/healthlightshop_532/public/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(218): preg_replace_callback('/\\[(\\[?)(usersw...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '<div class="fl-...')
#4 /www/healthlightshop_532/public/wp-content/plugins/bb-plugin/classes/class-fl-builder.php(1844): do_shortcode('<div class="fl-...')
#5 /www/healthlightshop_532/public/wp-content/plugins/bb-plugin/classes/clas" while reading response header from upstream, client: 67.173.15.26, server: shop.healthlightllc.com, request: "GET /my-customers/?v=32aec8db952d HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php7.4-fpm-healthlightshop.sock:", host: "shop.healthlightllc.com"
```

Comment: Can you give us the message and the stack trace from the critical error? It should be in your server or WordPress debug logs, and should have been emailed to you too. Please edit it into the question.

Comment: And if the example in the documentation is broken you could also contact the developer for help.

Comment: Thanks. But oops, I could have guessed that if I'd looked closely.

Comment: The problem is you're not setting $target_user. Where would you get that from? I don't think this belongs in a shortcode.