# Switch to user link

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have similar problem as here:[Switch to user link shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/390387/switch-to-user-link-shortcode)
I tried to adjust the code from developer FAQs this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_admin_switch_user', 10, 1 );

function display_admin_switch_user($order){
    $data  = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
    $customer_id     = $data['customer_id'];
    $customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );

    if ( method_exists( 'user_switching', 'maybe_switch_url' ) ) {
        $url = user_switching::maybe_switch_url( $customer );
        if ( $url ) {
            printf(
                '<a href="https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/%1$s">Switch to %2$s</a>',
                esc_url( $url ),
                esc_html( $customer->display_name )
            );
        }
    }   
}
```

but getting error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to user_switching::maybe_switch_url() must be an instance of WP_User, instance of WC_Customer given, called in /data/5/4/5467114b-e4f7-499d-b5d6-fb876c266fe2/perties.sk/sub/test/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(469) : eval()'d code on line 9 and defined in /data/5/4/5467114b-e4f7-499d-b5d6-fb876c266fe2/perties.sk/sub/test/wp-content/plugins/user-switching/user-switching.php:757 Stack trace: #0 /data/5/4/5467114b-e4f7-499d-b5d6-fb876c266fe2/perties.sk/sub/test/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(469) : eval()'d code(9): user_switching::maybe_switch_url(Object(WC_Customer)) #1 /data/5/4/5467114b-e4f7-499d-b5d6-fb876c266fe2/perties.sk/sub/test/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): display_admin_switch_user(Object(Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Overrides\Order)) #2 /data/5/4/5467114b-e4f7-499d-b5d6-fb876c266fe2/perties.sk/sub/test/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #3 /data/5/4/5467114b-e4f7-499d-b5d6-fb876 in /data/5/4/5467114b-e4f7-499d-b5d6-fb876c266fe2/perties.sk/sub/test/wp-content/plugins/user-switching/user-switching.php on line 757
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The error's pretty clear: "Argument 1 passed to user_switching::maybe_switch_url() must be an instance of WP_User, instance of WC_Customer given". Do you not see what you're doing wrong? The function doesn't accept WC_Customer, but that's what you're passing. If you need to know how to get the user object from a customer ID then that's a WooCommerce question, which would make it off topic, but if a customer ID is always the same as a user ID you can just use `WP_User` instead.

Comment: Thanks - below the code for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is tested code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_admin_switch_user', 10, 1 );

function display_admin_switch_user($order){
    $data  = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
    $user = $order->get_user();
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    
    if ( method_exists( 'user_switching', 'maybe_switch_url' ) ) {
        $url = user_switching::maybe_switch_url( $user );
        if ( $url ) {
            printf(
                '<a href="https://mysite.sk/plugins/user-switching/%1$s">Switch to %2$s</a>',
                esc_url( $url ),
                esc_html( $user->display_name )
            );
        }
    }   
}
```